# Apache2 - Redirecting a subdomain to another URL

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, mod-rewrite

I have two subdomains, a.website.com and b.website.com, pointing to the same IP address.  I want to redirect b.website.com to a.website.com:8080.  I have this in my .htaccess file...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} b\.website\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://b.website.com:8080$1 [L]
```

...but it does not work.

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Try adding the following to `.htaccess` in the parent directory above the directory of interest: `RedirectMatch ^/foo/$ /foo/bar/` or `RedirectMatch ^/foo/$ /bar/baz/`. Also see [How to get apache2 to redirect to a subdirectory](http://serverfault.com/q/9992/145545).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could always use a simple VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName b.website.com
  RedirectPermanent / http://a.website.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

If you prefer to go with the .htaccess file, you're just missing a % sign on the Rewrite Condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} b.website.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://a.website.com:8080$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried both and they didn't work.  I have mod_rewrite enabled and I have the VirtualHost in a separate site file.  Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: This works fine. 
I had a loop redirect problem, because I was pointing a subdomain to a  subfolder, and that subfolder was redirecting. Now, I redirect the subdomain to the URL that corresponds to the folder, and the 2nd redirection happens just fine!

Comment: How to do ot to preserve `http://` or `https://`, whatever way `b.website.com` was accessed in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

### Complementing the main answer

#### Redirect type

You can explicitly specify the type of redirect you pretend.
I suggest you use a temporary redirect (302) while testing the redirection rule.

```
# In a VirtualHost file
...
Redirect [301|302] /old_location http://new_domain/newlocation


# In a .httaccess file
...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new_domain/$1 [R=302,L]
```

#### Specify directory matching patterns

You could only redirect requests that match some pattern.

```
# In a VirtualHost file
...
RedirectMatch [301|302] ^/public/(.*)$ http://public.example.com/$1


# In a .httaccess file
...
RewriteRule ^/public/(.*)$ http://public.example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```